# Is speed ball really effective?

Tags: training, boxing, speed

I've seen enough videos about it and even more marketplaces selling them. But is it really that good? Can't it bring some wrong reflexes/etc?
Don't want to hit anybody, but men wearing it usually look a bit.. unusual.

PS

I'm just going to buy one, but is unsure if it worth it.

Comment: Are you talking about [the headband with an elastic band to a ball](https://youtu.be/eYA-g1Fppyk)?

Comment: @MacacoBranco, yes - I've seen different names - "fight ball", "speed ball" and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macaco gave you the [link to a video from R. Dewey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYA-g1Fppyk).
I think there is not much we could add to his comment.

It is fun.
It trains reflexes.
It is no training substitute for live training.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional speed ball with a platform is very effective if you plan to compete in western boxing or just want to simply get better at it. The reason is that the speed ball helps train your shoulders and forearms for prolonged periods of endurance. It will be very beneficial down the road if you decide to seriously take up boxing, since you’ll be able to work through fatigue better when doing pad work with a trainer.

Answer (score 0):

Many, many forms of training will be effective in some way.

A more useful question to ask is, "What training methods make the best use of my time?".

A height-adjustable floor-to ceiling ball (even if the ball is just a tennis ball, which you can make yourself very cheaply) will still train muscular endurance, with the important added benefits of improving reflexes, timing, and - if used properly - technique.

It's important to note that a floor-to ceiling ball can reinforce poor technique if you are a beginner. That being said, it is an excellent tool for the home for the following reasons:

1. It won't annoy other members of the home and/or neighbours nearly as much (it is much quieter, especially in the case of a tennis ball), meaning you can spend more time training.
2. All it requires is a small hook in the ceiling and a moveable weight anchor at floor level, so you can dismantle it and erect it easily, any time.